# Usage of "over"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> 1-  "If anything remains vague, it is only because of the dark cloud which
>   ***has come over*** my mind." (Context: He has been questioning for a while. And saying this sentence.)

What does "come over my mind" mean here?

> 2- Dark clouds ***have come over*** the city.

Can I use this sentence? What I mean is that: Dark clouds are above the city right now, we can't see the sky clearly.

I know in the first sentence "coming over" was used metaphorically. In the second sentence I used it literally.

> 3- She is a nervous flier. But once the plane ***got over*** the clouds, she
>   started to relax.

In this sentence, what does "get over" means? To me, "got over something" means like "jumping over the wall". I mean plane is no longer above the cloud, it skipped the cloud by going above it.

Answer (score 1):

"come over" means "cover". While "over" is usually used with verbs of movement, "above" is more frequently used with verbs of state. Notice you've said:

- Dark clouds **have come over** the city (and now **are above** the city).

Comment: Can I used it that way? Is it understandable as is? + By the way, I have edited my post.

Comment: Yes, you can use it that  way. In your new example (3), "get over" means "fly higher than the clouds", so they are now some distance under or below the plane.

Comment: I have a strange feeling saying if I use "over" this way, it sounds as if clouds have already skipped the city, they are no longer above the city or plane has already skipped clouds, it is no longer above the clouds. Like my "jumping over the wall" example. I think I have been accustomed to use "over" with verbs of movements. That is why those sentences seem weird to me.

Comment: When I say "Dark clouds have come over the city." , do listeners understand that clouds are still above the city?

Comment: Yes, the present perfect expresses that: past event with a present result (as a result of the clouds coming over the city, they are now above the city).

Comment: Hmm thanks. What about the "when the plane got over the clouds, she relaxed? Does that mean "when the plane is above the clouds" or "when the plane skipped the clouds by going over them" ?